# Convert DataReader to C# Object

Tags: c#, datatable, data-access-layer, datamapper, sqldatareader

I have a class

```
public class Person
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public List<string> Friends {get; set;}
}
```

I have a datareader which brings these values from Database and I want to populate the above class using DataReader.

Usually the details looks like the below

```
Name    Friends
John    Caleb
John    Matthew
John    Simon
Andrew  Bolton
Andrew  Mark
```

I need to group this according to Name and populate into the class with List of Friends for each Name.

Can someone help with this. I am not able to get the list of Friends with grouping. What will be the right code to achieve this logic.
Thank you

Comment: Please do not change the whole core of your question or nobody wants to answer it anymore...

Comment: sorry about that. Actually i am not able to read the datareader and get values.

Comment: No i am not using Dapper

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on Dapper.

Comment: Basically you will be filling a `List<person>` inside dataReader while loop, in which you could put a check for existing person by name and if exist then add the friend in the `friends` list only and if not then add new person

Comment: Remove that `()` after Person. As it is right now, your code doesn't compile.

Comment: So I tried to give you an answer. And yes for the problem in the question is maybe also another faster way to reading in and stuff. But i have doubts that you really work with a "friendship" relationship table. And I don't think that optimized to the extrem code will really help you in the end.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your Table like
(Name, Friend)

you have to read in you friendship table

then you have to group them
like with

```
var groupedTempList = tempList.GroupBy(a=>a.Name)
```

and then

```
List<Person> t = new List<Person>();

foreach(var Item in groupedTempList) 
{ 
    Person tP = new Person() {Name = Item.Key};
    foreach(YourTableEquivalentClass subitem in Item)
    {
        tP.Friends.Add(subitem.Friend);
    }
}
```

And here a Extension for the dbreader:

```
    public static int? GetNullableInteger(this SqlDataReader dbReader, string name)
    {
        var tVal = dbReader[name];
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(tVal)) return null;
        return new int?(int.Parse(tVal.ToString()));
    }

    public static int GetInteger(this SqlDataReader dbReader, string name)
    {
        int? tVal = dbReader.GetNullableInteger(name);
        if (tVal == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Der abgerufene int/int ist null/DbNull!");
        return (int)tVal;
    }


    public static string GetString(this SqlDataReader dbReader, string name)
    {
        var tVal = dbReader[name];
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(tVal)) return null;
        return tVal.ToString();
    }
```

And reading in stuff

```
                List<YourTableEquivalentClass> temp = new List<YourTableEquivalentClass>();
                string sqlComStr =
                      @"SELECT [Name]
                              ,[Friend]
                          FROM [YourDadabase].[dbo].[YourFriendshipTable]";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlComStr, con))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader dbReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (dbReader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (dbReader.Read())
                                {
                                    temp.Add(new YourTableEquivalentClass()
                                    {
                                        Name = dbReader.GetString("Name"),
                                        Friend = dbReader.GetString("Friend")
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: And yes maybe there is a shorter LINQ expression for the 1. and 2. code part.